# JFROG —> PUBLISH Swift Package Manager —> Consume that in various iOS Projects

Tags: ios, package, swift-package-manager, jfrog-insights

I am new to JFrog. Need your help regarding Swift package manager hosting and consuming.

JFrog supports swift registry. I have created one swift package manager and pushed it to JFrog-> Artifacts->local repository.(Following JFrog Documentation).

How to consume this Swift Package Manager in other projects?

I went through many questions here but I do not see the solution.

Please provide assistance regarding publishing part also.

Answer (score 1):

SPM packages can only be consumed via

1. Git URL
2. Directory paths on your own local machine

and they usually contain the source code of the package.

JFrog is used to distribute binaries of the libraries, not the source code.

So you should either decide on either consume the source code directly via SPM, or write a script that downloads the compiled binary library into your project where you then can reference it. But you can't use SPM to get a library from JFrog.

Comment: Can you please help me with any documentation about script? How to go ahead and consume binary libraries?

Comment: I can't help with the JFrog part, but I'm sure there are resources on that in the internet. But once you downloaded the xcframework binary to your project folder: just open the Xcode project, open the target's settings, go to the "General" tab, scroll down. There is a section called "Frameworks, Libraties and Embedded Content". Drag & Drop. Press "+", select "Add other", then"Add local", select the xcarchive.

Answer (score 1):

I created a public github repository where I store the Package.swift file that points to binaryTarget hosted on jfrog

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit more? I'm looking for a way to add the firebase iOS SDK as an SPM package through JFrog Artifactory, but haven't found a way to do so.